# Linq - How to query String[] of whole number as a string data type

Tags: c#, linq

I have this in variable c:

```
c = "1,2,3,5,12"
```

If i do:

```
p = ctx
      .PProject
      .Where(x => x.PCountryCode == cC && 
                  x.PParentalGuidence == r && 
                  c.Contains(x.PTtId.ToString()))
      .OrderByDescending(x => x.PId)
      .ToList();
```

`p` will return `2` if `x.PTtId = 12`.

But i need this to return `12`.

How do i solve this with whole numbers?

Comment: `c.Split(',').Contains(x.PTtId.ToString())` instead of `c.Contains(x.PTtId.ToString())`; otherwise you have false positive solution since `"12"` contains `"2"`

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, i get an error:
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0854 An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that

Comment: I put that code in another line:
string[] cc = c.Split(',');

Comment: It worked fine thanks :)

Comment: yes, you are quite right, it's better to *extract* `Split` from `Where` into `string[] cc = c.Split(',');` in order to compute the array just *once* before quering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your variable c should contain a comma-separated list of IDs. The first change string coma-separated list to fro eample array of IDs.

```
string c = "1,2,3,5,12";
var d = c.Split(',');
```

This array will use in second part of programm code:

```
p = ctx
  .PProject
  .Where(x => x.PCountryCode == cC && 
              x.PParentalGuidence == r && 
              d.Contains(x.PTtId.ToString()))
  .OrderByDescending(x => x.PId)
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're querying a database in your Linq expression.
If that is so, you should try to pass in an array of integers into the expression, in order to allow the interpreter to generate an `IN` expression that is manageable by an index.

Something as simple as:

```cs
string c = "1,2,3,5,12";
var idArray = c.Split(',').Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();

var p = ctx
  .PProject
  .Where(x => x.PCountryCode == cC && 
              x.PParentalGuidence == r && 
              idArray.Contains(x.PTtId))
  .OrderByDescending(x => x.PId)
  .ToList();
```

The code is almost the same, but the performance *could* be vastly different.

Check the generated SQL to know for sure.